# How to set tile image formats for many layers using the Geoserver REST api

Tags: geoserver, batch, geoserver-rest-api, pbf

I have over 400 layers in my Geoserver layer catalog. I would like to turn on the pbf tile image format option for all of them. see image below:

[image]

Is there a way of accomplishing this using the Geoserver REST api? I haven't been able to find an examples and it's a little confusing whether I should be editing the Geoserver layer files or the GWC files inside of Geoserver, as the pbf tiles are served through GWC using TMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modify the default tile format in Caching Defaults and add Vector Tiles format
   [image]
2. Then use the GeoServer REST API to republish the layers in batches.